# How to include uri relatively?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have built a model to be placed within my project, other than placing it in `~/.gazebo/models` (then later be used like `model://my_model`) in my `.world` file, could I include like the following or similar: (p.s. the following one seems doesn't work)

```
<include>
  <uri>model://$(find my_package)/models/my_model.sdf</uri>
</include>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16159/how-to-include-uri-relatively?/) by [medmuf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3234/medmuf/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Your `.world` files are in SDF, and unfortunately SDF doesn't support the kind of substitution you're trying to do. I believe the syntax you're using is supported on ROS launch files.

Gazebo will find your model as long as its parent path is listed on the environment variable `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`. So you can place it on a directory other than `~/.gazebo/models` and append that path to the environment variable.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [medmuf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3234/medmuf/) on 2017-05-15**:
Hooray! After setting `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` as my model path within `/etc/environment`, Gazebo did find customized models. Although I expect relative uri's are supported built-in. :-P

**Comment by [cadbury](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27095/cadbury/) on 2020-06-10**:
Hey, can you please tell me the steps on how to do that?

**Comment by [LR](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34013/lr/) on 2020-10-18**:
can i use the absolute path in  tag?